# How I can get hooked application url on djangocms

Tags: django, django-cms

Have for this right way something like this:

```
apphook_pool.get_apphook('MyApp').get__url()
```

Or I shoud do query to cms.models.Page and search there 'MyApp'?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply `reverse` the index view of your apphook. Alternatively, you can get the url via `Page.objects.public().get(application_urls='path.to.app.urls').get_absolute_url()`.